Is there a difference between "there is" versus "there exists"?
I have heard the phrases "there is" and "there exists" used interchangeably, but I am now wondering, is there a difference between them, and if so, what is it? Also, have philosophers talked about this topic, and if they have, can I read some texts on that subject?

Some philosophers do make the distinction. In the Meinongian tradition, the existential quantifier ("there is") is divested of existential import and the offensive to Kant existence predicate ("there exists") is used to fill the gap. This is done to make sense of talking about non-existents, like unicorns and round squares, without paraphrase, see SEP, Nonexistent Objects. Some theists distinguish being and existence to say that God (or One in neo-Platonism) is the source of all existence and so the concept cannot apply to him, etc.

""That depends on what the meaning of 'is' is."  William Jefferson Clinton - 1998

Your question seems to assume that there might be some definitive difference  between the meanings of the two words, and whether that difference has been explored by philosophers. I suggest you regard the question the other was around, by assuming the words can be used interchangeably in most cases, and asking whether any philosophers have proposed that they should be used to denote separate concepts. Remember that words have no inherent meaning- meaning is derived from usage.
In everyday speech, the word 'exist' would not normally be used instead of 'is' to denote an absence, as in a phrase such as 'there isn't any milk left'.
The word 'is' can also be used descriptively in ways in which it would not be sensible to substitute the word 'exist'. For example, you might say that Marco Ocram is really idiotic. There are many other contexts in which the word 'is' would be appropriate while the word 'exist' would not, such as...
Is it true you have pawned my Rolex?
Home is where the heart is.
How is your mother?


I have heard the phrases "there is" and "there exists" used interchangeably,

in (mainstream?) mathematical logic, both are just the informal/natural language manner of writing existencial quantification ∃

but I am now wondering, is there a difference between them, and if so, what is it?

so there is (!) no difference, at least in this context

The word exist specifically refers to an object or subject that has "being", whereas the word is has a greater scope and can include concepts and abstractions.
